# パラメータが多い時のみMyBatisがエラーを出す

Tags: java, sql, amazon-redshift

動作環境

```
org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.7
```

RedShiftに接続してデータ取得をしています

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE
 <foreach item="item" collection="lists" open="(" close=")" separator=" OR ">
        (xxx BETWEEN #{item.From} AND #{item.To})
 </foreach>
```

mybatisに設定するパラメータのlistのサイズが3000以上くらいのときエラーを吐いて、抽出に失敗します。サイズが少ないと条件通り抽出できます。

```
2015-11-07 12:46:26,672 [main] ERROR Main - org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
### The error may exist in com/xxx/sql/sql_redshift.xml
### The error may involve com.xxx.sql.findXXXs-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
```

クエリが長すぎることのIOエラーのような感じですが、なにかいい方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2):

postgresqlの設定にある max_stack_depth の値を増やすことで一応は対応できます。(デフォルト値は2,048kB)

ただし超絶巨大なIN句を使ったクエリはパフォーマンス面も悪く、あまりに長大なSQLになるとJava側(Mybatis)がOutOfMemory Errorの可能性も出てきますので、オススメはしません。

抽出条件の見直しをするか、複数回のクエリに分割してJava側で結果を結合するのが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

listが3000くらいだと...SQL自体の長さ制限とかSQLパーサの限界に引っかかったりしませんかね？
そこで生成されるSQLを、そのままpgadminで実行したらどうなりますか？

以下のページを見てみるとNOTを1万くらいつないだSQLを実行すると怒られてるみたいですし、mybatisの限界というよりもPostgresの限界って可能性は無いかな～？
http://postgresql.g.hatena.ne.jp/umitanuki/20090220/1235094391